# log4j2 Async appender works only for debug level

Tags: log4j2, asyncappender

I have an Async appender that works only when I set the level=debug. For "error" level it does not log anything.

```
<Configuration packages="com.custom.appender">
<Appenders>
<CustomLogger name="customLogger"/>
<Async name="customAsync" bufferSize="2" includeLocation="flase">
    <AppenderRef ref="customLogger"/>
</Async>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
<logger name="com.mypackage" level="error">
    <AppenderRef ref="customAsync"/>
</logger>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I am not sure what I am missing in this configuration. This is the custom appender that I am trying to use

```
package com.custom.appender
@Plugin(name = "CustomLogger", category = "Core", elementType = "appender",   printObject = true)
public class CustomLogger extends AbstractAppender {

private static volatile CustomLogger instance;

public CustomLogger(final String name, final Filter filter,
        final Layout<? extends Serializable> layout) {
    super(name, filter, layout);
}

@PluginFactory
public static CustomLogger createAppender(
        @PluginAttribute("name") String name,
        @PluginAttribute("ignoreExceptions") boolean ignoreExceptions,
        @PluginElement("Layout") Layout layout,
        @PluginElement("Filters") Filter filter) {
    if (layout == null) {
        layout = PatternLayout.createDefaultLayout();
    }

    instance = new CustomLogger(name, filter, layout);
    return instance;
}

public static CustomLogger getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

@Override
public void append(LogEvent event) {
    //Log the event to mongoDB
}
```

}

Comment: What type of appender you are trying to use ? Is it a console appender ?

Comment: I don't think refering a logger element from Async appender element is correct. From there you have to access an appender.

Comment: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Comment: I am trying to use a custom appender, added that code to the post

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
<Configuration packages="com.custom.appender">
    <Appenders>
        <Async name="customAsync" bufferSize="2" includeLocation="flase">
            <AppenderRef ref="customConsoleLogger"/>
        </Async>
        <Console name="customConsoleLogger" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.mypackage" level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="customAsync"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: This code works but when I switch the logger in Async to use my custom logger, thats when I am having problem. In my custom logger I am logging the event to mongoDB, the control goes in my appender but nothing gets logged in mongoDB when level is error. If I change the level to debug I see my events in mongoDB

Comment: @Anyz Do you have any error logs in there? When you set the log level to ERROR you will only see ERROR and FATAL logs.

Comment: I think I may have found the cause. I don't think it has anything to do with level. When I am logging ERROR I don't have that many events going to the appender and I am trying to connect to mongoDB in my append() method and it is failing on my mongo write. Interestingly I am not getting any errors but I put some explicit logging and can see it just stops on my write mongo command.